# Why is my linear velocity coming back as 0 even though my gravity appears set

Tags: c++, box2d

I am using Box2D and I am porting some code from an older version to a newer one. One the older version everything moves fine, however, on the newer version gravity doesn't appear to effect LinearVelocity. Am I doing this wrong?

Ok here is the code...

Making my world (gx=0 gy=-10)...

```
b2Vec2 gravity;
gravity.Set(gx, gy);
LOGD("Gravity set to %f, %f", gx, gy);
world = new b2World(gravity);
```

Create Body...

```
b2BodyDef bd;
bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bd.position.Set(x, y);
b2Body* b = world->CreateBody(&bd);
b2PolygonShape pd;
b2Vec2 center;
center.Set(x, y);
pd.SetAsBox(width, height, center, angle);
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &pd;
fixtureDef.density = density;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
b->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

But when I run through my step...

```
LOGD("Gravity is %f", world->GetGravity().y);
world->Step(dt, iterations, iterations);
for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    b2Vec2 position = b->GetPosition();
    float32 angle = b->GetAngle();
    float32 yVelocity = b->GetLinearVelocity().y;
    LOGD("Stepping %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %f \n", position.x, position.y, angle, yVelocity);
}
```

The console output for old is (Both include ground box)...

```
D/Native  ( 4243): Stepping 0.00 -1.02 0.00 -0.500000 
D/Native  ( 4243): Stepping 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.000000 
D/Native  ( 4243): Stepping 0.00 -1.06 0.00 -1.000000 
D/Native  ( 4243): Stepping 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.000000 
D/Native  ( 4243): Stepping 0.00 -1.13 0.00 -1.500000 
D/Native  ( 4243): Stepping 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.000000
```

Everything looks even and nice here but in mine things get weird...

```
D/Native  ( 4310): Stepping 0.00 -0.86 0.02 -0.000000 
D/Native  ( 4310): Stepping 0.00 -10.00 0.00 0.000000 
D/Native  ( 4310): Stepping 0.00 -0.73 0.04 0.000000 
D/Native  ( 4310): Stepping 0.00 -10.00 0.00 0.000000 
D/Native  ( 4310): Stepping 0.00 -0.60 0.05 0.000000 
D/Native  ( 4310): Stepping 0.00 -10.00 0.00 0.000000
```

So as you can see in addition to having an angle (which the original one did not) there is no linear velocity in the y direction. Did something change that I am missing here?

BTW here is the old way they created a world, also their code didn't use fixtures just shapes...

```
b2AABB aabb;
aabb.lowerBound.Set(x1, y1);
aabb.upperBound.Set(x2, y2);

b2Vec2 gravity;
gravity.Set(gx, gy);

world = new b2World(aabb, gravity, canSleep);
```

Comment: Shape `pd` is not setting to `fixtureDef`. And, show definition of `fixtureDef`, please.

Comment: Sorry added density is 1

Comment: also here is the code.... https://github.com/jrgleason/Box2DvJBox2D

Comment: I think it has something to do with the box's origin being at -1. Everything looks ok when I set it to something positive (say +4) but then it seems to come to a stop at 1.0. Is there something I have to set to change the world origin?

Comment: There is no difference for box2d. Reason somewhere near.

Comment: Reason somewhere near? What does that mean?

Comment: Try to create simple app, with all code in one function and without using of any external variables and constants. If there will be all ok, then compare this code with your persent code.

Comment: I did that is the other comment. It seems to somewhat work (-1 still doesn't work) but settles at 1.0

Comment: I also confirmed the old code works until 1 so I am pretty sure it is a world (fixture) origin issue of some sort.

Comment: Using a positive number and shifting the view matrix in OpenGL works fine but I would like to do this without shifting the matrix in GL I would like to do it in the Box2D code

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though Bounding Boxes have become [obsolete](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7467) so I am not sure there is a way to use a negative location in Box2D anymore. So for me I had to shift all objects to assume a ground of 1 and update my translation to OpenGL accordingly. I am still not 100% sure this is the end all be all answer so I will not accept it and I will hope someone will give a better answer.